# How to add a separate permalink icon/button on Tumblr blog page?

Tags: tumblr, links

I have added permalinks to my photographs. When on my Tumblr blog page these are accessible when you click on the timestamp, which is OK, but if a non-Tumblr user visited the blog, he/she would most probably not realise that.

Can I add a separate, more visible icon or button for permalinks?

(I add photos through text post option so directly clicking photo does nothing!)